# sysmalloc assertion error when initializing 2D vector

Tags: c++, malloc

Sometimes when initialing a temporary 2D vector with `std::vectorstd::vector<int> temp(num_vertices_);``, c++ gives me a sysmalloc assertion error.

```
void Grafo::remove_vertice(int v)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < adj[v].size(); i++)
    {
        num_arestas_--;
    }

    adj[v].clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < adj.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < adj[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            if (adj[i].size() == 1)
            {
                if (adj[i][j] > v)
                {
                    adj[i][j] = adj[i][j] - 1;
                    break;
                }
                if (adj[i][j] == v)
                {
                    adj[i].erase(adj[i].begin() + j);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (auto x : adj[i])
                {
                    if (adj[i][j] > v)
                    {
                        adj[i][j] = adj[i][j] - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (adj[i][j] == v)
                    {
                        adj[i].erase(adj[i].begin() + j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    adj[v].insert(adj[v].begin(), -1);
    num_vertices_--;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> temp(num_vertices_);
    int lacoTemp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++)
    {
        if (adj[i].empty())
        {
            lacoTemp++;
        }
        for (int x : adj[i])
        {
            if (x != -1)
            {
                temp[lacoTemp].insert(temp[lacoTemp].begin(), x);
                lacoTemp++;
            }
        }
    }

    adj.clear();
    adj.resize(num_vertices_);

    for (int i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++)
    {
        adj[i] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

My input:
8 12

R 0 7

E

I 4 1

Q 5

N

I 5 4

R 0 6

E

Q 1

Grafo: malloc.c:2617: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

Comment: Probably a buffer overrun causing undefined behavior (in this case, corrupting the heap).

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to answer your question.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Also, if you wrote this code yourself, you have not mentioned any efforts you made in debugging this code.

Comment: You do `for (auto x : adj[i]) { ... adj[i].erase(...) }`. This exhibits undefined behavior, since it invalidates iterators that the loop is using. It also doesn't look right, as `x` is never actually used in the body of the loop.

Comment: Given the comment @IgorTandetnik made, you could have erased all of the elements that are equal to `v` first using `adj[i].erase(std::remove_if(adj[i].begin(), adj[i].end(), [&](auto &val) { return val == v; }). adj[i].end());`.  That does not require any `for` loop.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that first loop should be replaced with `num_arestas_ -= adj[v].size();`. And `adj[i][j] = adj[i][j] - 1;` could be simplified to `adj[i][j]--;`.

Comment: Also, in `if (adj[i].size() == 1) ... else ...` the two branches of the `if` do exactly the same thing. The second branch will work just as well when the size is 1. There's no need for that test. It's unusual, however, to write `for (auto x : adj[i]) ...` and not use `x` anywhere in the controlled expression. I can't recommend a replacement because I don't see what this code is supposed to do.